# How easy is it to get Linux.Ekoms.1?

Tags: security, malware, jpeg

I read about this malware, one of the biggest specimens of malware on the Linux news right now. How easy is it to get? Paranoia has gotten the better of me. According to the sites I visited, it is able to take screen captures and send them back to the creators of the malware.

Answer (score 4):

Impossible from what I gather. Unless you install it yourself. There seems to be a way to install it in mozilla as an extension. But yes, you will need to install that extension yourself. Not much of a "trojan"...

And from what I found out you have some more problems getting it to run.  A lot of the Ubuntu users probably do not even get it to build due to an old used libc. Besides you needing to use an end of life Ubuntu you also need to kill pulseaudio yourself for the trojan to be able to use it. You also need to disable compositing yourself or the only screenshot it takes is a desktop image.

And now for the kicker: the group/person that detected this trojan does not disclose where they found it, do no even provide the source code but they are willing to sell you an anti-virus software for you to use!

B O G U S.

Comment: Phew. I'm so relieved. I thought I was going to be under what I call "malware stress" again. For SOME REASON, I only get malware stress when using Windows... I wonder why that is? :P